# How to iterate over json array

Tags: objective-c, json

I have this json code

```
{
  "apps": [
    {
      "com.eeenmachine.tinytowers": [
        {
          "text": "one"
        },
        {
          "text": "two"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

And i am trying to get all the text values.

Trying with this code

```
NSArray *titles = [jsArray[@"apps"] valueForKey:game];
        NSLog(@"[DEBUG]titles %@",titles);
        for (id obje in titles){
            NSLog(@"[DEBUG]obje %@",obje);
            NSLog(@"[DEBUG]obje_class %@",[obje class]);
        }
```

Problem is that I don't get each text value , instead i get all the values.

Output:

```
obje (
            {
            text = one;
        },
            {
            text = two;
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your sample data there are a lot of arrays (`[`, `]`) as well as dictionaries (`{`, `}`). For example the value for key `apps` is an array containing a single dictionary. Your code does not appear to be dealing with these extra levels.

HTH